# What should a 21st century Euler attempt?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Euler at the start of his career found the exact sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. My question is: What could a 21st century Euler possibly attempt to solve? Are there any similar "elementary" problems which a mature mathematician in his late teens/early twenties could attempt to solve? By "elementary" I'm referring to problems whose intuitive solution could possibly be understood by a high school student.

This might sound like a stupid question but I'm just curious.

Thanks in advance for trying to help!

Comment: What do you mean by an "intuitive solution"? In what way was Euler's summation an "intuitive solution" of that problem? And how can we know whether a high school student could understand the solution to a problem, when we have no idea what a solution of the problem will look like?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought Euler's initial solution was based on unproven manipulations, thus the solution would count as inutitive I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I think relevant to the discussion. Also, I make a disclaimer now, much of what follows is my opinion based on what I've seen. If there are mathematicians or anecdotes that you think would give a better perspective on the situation, I'd love to hear about them.

---

It is worth noting that Euler's initial proof of the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, whilst elegant, isn't rigourous by today's standards. It showed great intuition though, and that's how the sort of discoveries you are talking about are often made. A relative newcomer to mathematics has an insight which leads them to make some progress on a problem. However, their intuition often leads to non-rigorous arguments. With some luck, the argument can be made rigorous by those with a larger mathematical toolbox.

Another example of such a mathematician is Srinivasa Ramanujan, an Indian mathematician who made many independent discoveries with almost no tertiary level mathematics education. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan):

> "The limitations of his knowledge were as startling as its profundity. Here was a man who could work out modular equations and theorems... to orders unheard of, whose mastery of continued fractions was... beyond that of any mathematician in the world, who had found for himself the functional equation of the zeta function and the dominant terms of many of the most famous problems in the analytic theory of numbers; and yet he had never heard of a doubly periodic function or of Cauchy's theorem, and had indeed but the vaguest idea of what a function of a complex variable was...". When asked about the methods employed by Ramanujan to arrive at his solutions, Hardy said that they were "arrived at by a process of mingled argument, intuition, and induction, of which he was entirely unable to give any coherent account." He also stated that he had "never met his equal, and can compare him only with Euler or Jacobi."

I would imagine that someone looking to make such discoveries today would start in the areas that Ramanujan worked in; whilst they are incredibly deep, they contain many results which are easy to understand. For example, an infinite sum for $\dfrac{1}{\pi}$ is easy to understand, even though it may be incredibly hard to find.

The last point I would like to make is that while Euler's discovery was actually the solution to the well-known Basel problem, Ramanujan's discoveries weren't in the form of solving open problems, at least, not any that he was aware of. Ramanujan worked in isolation and made amazing discoveries by exploring mathematics, letting his curiousity and intuition lead him. I would encourage a modern day Euler or Ramanujan to do the same; the brilliance such a person would possess may allow them to answer questions we have never even thought to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Goldbach's conjecture would seem like a a good start, albeit it has defied attempts to prove it for nearly three centuries :D. When the `young-but-mature' mathematician fails, (s)he can at least have a good time reading Doxiadis' eponymous novel.

On a more serious note, one has to keep in mind that the notion of a 'universal mathematician' has been rather out of date for a while - the last one labeled as such, as far as I know, was Kolmogorov who produced his best work in the 1st half of the century. Why do I consider *that* to be relevant to your question? Because specialization seems to have focused research on more detailed (or more esoteric, if you will) questions. (OK, this is a major oversimplification, but I don't want to write a diatribe.) Such questions are hardly accessible by mathematicians in their late teens/early twenties, as they presuppose a corpus of knowledge which takes a lot of time to master.

In short, then, even the existence of such problems is hard to prove...

Comment: [Kolmogorov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov) is older than that god: [von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann).

Comment: By 8 months :)? Deciding whether Kolmogorov or von Neumann (or Poincaré) was the last universalist requires a level of familiarity with their work which I'm not pretentious enough to claim to have :). Anyhow, this is largely semantics, isn't it?

Comment: I wasn't trying to claim von Neumann was the last one. I was just bringing him into the loop.

Comment: Sure, no worries!